# scientific notation's type

Tags: c++, types, scientific-notation

```
int s = 1e9;
```

What is type of `1e9` and how precise is it? (Is it exactly equal to 1000000000?)

Printing type of a value/variable to `stdout` would be useful if it's possible.

Comment: I believe s should be a double, not an int.

Comment: Yep, it's double. And you cannot print the type of a variable, C++ doesn't have means for that (I believe it is called reflection).

Comment: @Violet: Actually, that's a question that [we answered earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7601533/print-types-of-arbitrary-c-expressions).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`1e9` is a `double` that has an exact representation in the IEEE floating point representation. The C++ standard doesn't mandate IEEE floating point.

`s` is an `int`, so the `double` value will be automatically converted to an `int`. How this takes place is to some extent up to the implementation. On most machines nowadays, this conversion means `s` will be given an initial value of 1000000000.

Comment: Why it is equal to 1000000000? If it is the real scientific data, it should be 1.0 x e^9 that is something different, no? What if I need the TRUE scientific value?

Comment: @Gupta - 1e9 is short for 1.0 x 10^9, not 1.0 x e^9. The "e" in this context means "base 10 exponent" rather than Euler's number *e* (2.718281828...).

Answer (score 5):

For what it's worth, you can write code that shows that `1e9` has type `double`:

```
#include <iostream>

void show_type(double value) { 
    std::cout << "type = double\n"; 
}
void show_type(...) {
    std::cout << "Type != double\n";
}

int main() { 
    show_type(1e9);
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, if you don't know what type it has, it's quite a bit more work to provide an overload for every possible type, but the principle is the same nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

If you change it to `float` or `double` it's going to be pretty precise, but *not every computation with it will be exact* (thnks to Kerrek SB), there are limits to precision.

Note, that the precision is *not* the property of *notation*, anyway, the notation is the exactness itself.

Comment: "You can't do any exact computations" is wrong. The correct statement is that "not *every* computation will be exact". (For example, rational operations where the denominator of the ultimate resulting value is a power of two have a good chance of being exact.)

Comment: @KerrekSB, almost agreed. I'd propose yet another wording: you can not rely on any computation to be exact. But, honestly, I think it is the last paragraph that actually answers the question.

Comment: I don't know. I think you *can* rely on `9.0 / 3.0` to be exactly `3.0`... Why not?

Comment: @KerrekSB, well, I wasn't talking about the computation with at least one unknown :) Besides, none of your operands is 1e9 :P

Comment: Hm, same thing: `double x = 9.0, y = 3.0;` Now the value of `x/y` should be reliably `3.0`, non? My point is that there *are* computations that are indeed exact, and predictably so. (Likewise for `1e9 / 1e8`.)

Comment: True again. It's just that you normally (not always, you're right) don't know if your computations is going to be exact unless you really watch your steps. But well, I'll edit your wording in.

Comment: There's a certain sense that all operations are exact.  Over the set of floating point values, as defined by the floating point processor.  The real problem is that floating point numbers aren't real numbers; not only may the result be different than the same operation over real numbers, but many of the basic laws of real number arithmetic, like the associativity of addition, don't hold.